# Error when clearing a scene in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Need your help here !

I receive that error when I try to reload my scene with the help of a "cut-scene" that I called loader.lua :

```
?:0: attempt to index a nil value
stack traceback:
           ?: in function '_isWithinBounds'
           ?: in function '?'
           ?: in function <?:449>
           ?: in function <?:205>
```

loader.lua :

```
local composer = require("composer")

local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    composer.removeScene("game")

end

function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    composer.gotoScene("game")

end

function scene:hide( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

end

function scene:destroy( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

end
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

return scene
```

And finally the caller function :

```
function buttonEvent( event )
            if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
                print("Clicked")
                composer.gotoScene("loader")
            end
        end
```

I tried to cancel my timers and added everything to the sceneGroup self.view to clear the scene but I got this error every time!

Any help will be more than welcome !
Thanks !

EDIT:

Got rid of the

```
composer.removeScene("game")
```

That was calling a nil value and now my error went out but I got an empty black screen :/

And added

```
local sceneGroup = self.view
if (event.phase == did) then
    composer.gotoScene("game")
end
```

To the scene:show function of loader.lua

I tried to set :

```
composer.recycleOnSceneChange
```

To True and False but it only changed the Debug screen Output..

The Debug screen shows me nothing when

```
composer.recycleOnSceneChange = false
```

But shows me :

```
15:57:55.433  COMPOSER: 
15:57:55.433  A total of [1] scene(s) have been removed.
15:57:55.433
```

When

```
composer.recycleOnSceneChange = true
```

In game.lua everything is set in the scene:create function and the game logic is in the scene:show.

Comment: When `creat` you remove the `game` scene (`game` will be `nil`); And you goto `game` scene when `show`, its impossible.

Comment: You need to put the whole code.

Comment: @Albert Thank you ! My error disappeared ! But now I got a black screen ^^' ?

Comment: @Liace Could you post your whole code?